# extra space in magento 1.9.0.1 home page

Tags: magento-1.9, css, home

I am a week into magento its being used as a CMS, the issue i have on the home page the slider has a large space on the bottom of the image can advice.

see http://thenet4business.com/magento/index.php/

regards

Storm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though its not related to magento but css, however, the solution is to edit the `styles.css` file found at

```
/magento/skin/frontend/default/pagayo-theme-001/css/
```

and comment the following class at line# 3740

```
.homepage {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: @storm , accept the answer if it helped you, by clicking the ticket so it turns to green.

Comment: I spent a fair amount of time on this thank you very much.Now time to understand how Magento works it seems a great tool regards